# Make current page on menu appear with different colour

Tags: html, css, fonts, menu, dreamweaver-templates

Using html, css and a DW template, how do I make the font colour of the link for my current page in my menu appear with a separate colour than the other page links? I don't know JavaScript etc.

Comment: This is a simple CSS problem, be sure to do some research on your own before you post.

Comment: You have provided no code and insufficient explanation of your problem. Improve your question. http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Answer (score 0):

```js
function changecolor(colorhere){
var x=document.getElementById("text");
x.style="color:"+colorhere;
  }
```

```html
<p id="text">
  Some and so on text here
</p><br>
<button onclick='changecolor("red")'>Red</button>
<button onclick='changecolor("blue")'>Blue</button>
<button onclick='changecolor("yellow")'>Yellow</button>
```

Change color using javascript!